# Twilio message not received

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio with my parse app. I am sending message fron NodeJS. I was doing before with Test credentials and it was working fine now when I have moved to premium the message is not received.

```
client.messages.create({
    to: "+92334*******",
    from: "+12569******",
    body: "Confirmation code is " + code,
}, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        promise.reject(err.message);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(message.sid);
    }
});
```

The message is successfully sent however it's not received on the device.

Comment: Have you checked your logs in the [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console)? Do they say the message was "sent" or "delivered"?

Answer (score 1):

I have long enjoyed Twilio, I have been cases when the SMS was delivered late.

You’ve tried sending an SMS message, but it didn’t arrive. Fear not! This article is designed to help you walk through troubleshooting steps to diagnose, and hopefully fix, the problem.
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-troubleshoot-if-an-sms-message-sent-from-twilio-didnt-arrive

Check Programmable SMS Logs https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/logs